# How to load the contents of the memory address stored in a register in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

I'm new to assembly and am trying to iterate over a string stored in memory. I'm able to get the address of the string using `lea` (load effective address) instruction but I want to now use that address stored in a register.

Is there an analog to `lw` which could be used as follows:

```
lea string, %edx     ; Load effective address of string into edx
lw %edx, %eax        ; Load eax with the value stored where edx points 

...
string:
    .string "Hello"
```

Comment: The Intel has syntax `[address]` for memory access, can be applied to almost all basic instructions, `mov` in your case just to fetch value, but also basic arithmetic works. But as you are using gas/AT&T syntax, it's different, the memory reference is then `offset(r_base,r_index,index_scale_factor)` where `offset` and `index_scale_factor` are numbers (or symbols). so `mov eax,[edx] ; load first 4 characters of string` = `movl (%edx),%eax`, and more complex ones like `mov al,[arrayX+edi*8+esi]` = `movb arrayX(%esi, %edi, 8), %al`

Comment: That said it looks like you are trying to GUESS the instructions. Please don't do that, even if you would get probably few times away with it, sooner or later you would run into something, like the most common SO assembly question "divide overflow", because people expect `div %ebx` to divide eax/ebx, while it does not. Get some instruction set reference guide, and get some GAS/AT&T assembly syntax reference guide. And go through them quickly few times. (and possible memory addressing modes in 8086 mode are very limited... also your `lea string, %edx` is invalid on 8086, makes me wonder...)

Comment: @Ped7g I'm actually using this as a reference for instructions http://flint.cs.yale.edu/cs421/papers/x86-asm/asm.html#registers , I could not find something like `lw` so I asked the question. You are right though, I need to understand addressing modes better.

Comment: That's like asking me to downvote you straightaway... At your link, just under the registers chapter is *"Memory and Addressing Modes"*, where that fugly GAS syntax is explained (sorry, I'm biased, I hate it). And under that two headlines away are "Instructions", with subchapter "Data Movement Instructions" ... can you even read, or are you just mindlessly clicking on buttons on screen? ... Anyway, a reasonably complete instruction reference is also at: http://x86.renejeschke.de/ (and there're several similar pages). The GAS syntax docs => either official AS docs, or search, I will not.

Comment: Got it. I was already doing something very similar only I was using the wrong operation suffix, my bad. I'm out of my depth here so apologies for the really stupid mistake.

Answer (score 1):

"mov" is what you're looking for, with indirect addressing (which has some register restrictions based on whichever mode you're in)

Comment: Can you give me an example? I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong when I try to do `mov %edx, %eax` because that just moves the contents and therefore a large number into eax, but not the contents of the memory address.

Comment: Right, you're not using indirect addressing there.  You'll need to find how to do that in AT&T syntax.  I'm essentially read-only for AT&T syntax.  I hate it with a passion, so only do Intel syntax now like MOV EAX,[EDX]